# Using MSBuild to filter out unwanted extensions and folders

Tags: msbuild

Using MSBuild, how can I filter out unwanted extensions in my project (and folders potentially)?

Extensions like .cs, .resx files etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
<ItemGroup>
<MyGroup Include="Directory\**" Exclude="**\*.cs;**\*.resx" />
</ItemGroup>
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2006/03/08/546583.aspx